# how to create array from realm result

Tags: swift, realm

i want to create an array from Realm result

```
[0] SaveCalendar {
    id = 1;
    color = #F0C0DD;
    date = 2018-04-11 14:05:00;
},
[1] SaveCalendar {
    id = 2;
    color = #EDBBB5;
    date = 2018-04-12 13:07:00;
},
```

I want to convert it like this way : `[#F0C0DD : 2018-04-11 14:05:00 , #EDBBB5 : 2018-04-12 13:07:00]`

Comment: Isn't RealmResults already an array?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    var calendarList =  Array(realm.objects(SaveCalendar.self)) 
    var strCalendarList = [[String:String]]()

    for calender in calendarList {
        strCalendarList.append(["\(calender.color)":"\(calender.date)"])
    }

    print(strCalendarList)
```

result 
`[["#EDBBB5": "2018-04-11 14:05:00"], ["#EDBBB5": "2018-04-11 14:05:00"]]`

Comment: thaks bro, how to remove [ ] ?

Comment: @IrwanMadness Why you want to do this this way you will not get the value

Comment: because i need data for send to API like this : #F0C0DD : 2018-04-11 14:05:00 , #EDBBB5 : 2018-04-12 13:07:00

Comment: I do not think that API receives it like this `["#F0C0DD : 2018-04-11 14:05:00 "," #EDBBB5 : 2018-04-12 13:07:00"]` or `[{"EDBBB5":"2018-04-11 14:05:00"},{"EDBBB5":"2018-04-11 14:05:00"}]` ، But other than that I think it is not considered a particular format